# Understanding vital part of the proof that a closed interval is connected.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Part of the proof that a closed interval in $ℝ$ is connected usually relies on the below fact.

Given that $W \neq \varnothing$ is closed and open in a closed interval.

There exists such $x_0$ and $\epsilon > 0$ that $(x_0-\epsilon, x_0 + \epsilon) \subset W$. We then define $r$ as:
$$
r = \sup \{ p: [x_0, x_0 + p) \subset W \} 
$$

Then it is stated that since $W$ is closed, then it follows that $x_0 + r \in W$.

I can't understand why the latter holds. I know it has to do with the fact that there is a sequence from $W$ and since it's closed then the limit of that sequence, which is $sup$ will belong to it.

I am confused, since the sequence is supposed to consist of $p$'s from above definition but then it is stated that $x_0 + r$ belongs to $W$ and not just $r$.

Would appreciate any help on that. Thanks.

Comment: The supremum is taken over $p$ values but the elements of $W$ under consideration are all of the form $x_0+p$. There's no reason to expect $r$ to be in $W$.

Comment: Why is there a reason then to expect that $x_0 + r$ will be in $W$?

Comment: Can you please clarify "W is closed and open..." ?

Comment: @Koro It means that the set is closed and open at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $O=(a,b)$ (or maybe $O=(a,1]$) be a basic neighbourhood of $x_0 + r$ in $[0,1]$, so at least we know $a < x_0 + r$ so $a- x_0 < r$. From the latter we know that $a-x_0$ cannot be an upper bound for $\{p: [x_0, x_0+p) \subseteq W\}$ (as sup is the least upper bound, and $a-x_0$ is smaller) so there is some $p' (\le r)$ such that $p' > a-x_0$ and $[x_0, x_0 + p') \subseteq W$, and so $[x_0, x_0 + p'] \subseteq \overline{W} = W$. So $a < x_0 + p'$ and so $x_0 + p' \in O$. So $O$ intersects $W$ in $x_0+p’$ and so as $O$ was an arbitrary basic neighbourhood of $x_0+ r$, $x_0 + r \in \overline{W}=W$ again using that $W$ is closed.

Answer (score 2):

More generally:

> If $A \subseteq \mathbb R$ is non-empty and bounded above, then $\sup A \in \overline A$.

Indeed, let $\alpha = \sup A$. Then, for each $n \in \mathbb N$, there is $a_n \in A$ such that $b_n=\alpha - \frac1n < a_n \le \alpha$. Then $b_n \to \alpha$ implies $a_n \to \alpha$. Thus, $\alpha \in \overline A$.